# Age rule is not getting executed properly

Tags: jess

I am trying to fire these two rules but i am getting the same output for both the rules. 
  [This is the output i am getting for both.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1UVK.png)

```
(defrule old-male
    ?gender <- (gender m)  
    ?age <- (age ?age&:(> ?age 35))
       =>
       (printout t "Person is male & older. This Person must go after older females!" crlf)
       (retract ?gender)
       (retract ?age)
       (ask-start-again))

(defrule young-male
 ?gender <- (gender m)
?age <- (age ?age&:(< ?age 35))
   =>
   (printout t "Person is male & younger. This Person must go after younger females!" crlf)
   (retract ?gender)
   (retract ?age)
   (ask-start-again))

(reset)
(run)
```

Please advice what i need to do to fix this.

And also is there a way to store the inputs that are given (gender, age and name) and compare them with another person.?
Thank you!

I have added the rule you advised and also another rule for the list.

```
(defrule print-solution

  =>  
  (printout t "Name   Age   Gender" crlf)
  (printout t "--------------------------------------" crlf))
```

I have no errors but the (print-all-persons)rule is not getting executed. Did I miss anything? Kindly advice.

[This is the new output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdaGD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same name in the binding to the entire fact (`?age <- ...`) and the first item of the ordered fact (`(age ?age&:...`). Just use another name for the latter.

```
(defrule old-male
    ?gender <- (gender m)  
    ?age <- (age ?a&:(> ?a 35))
 =>
   ...
```

For storing age and gender of several persons at the same time a template such as the following can be used. A name is added so that there is a distinction when two üersons of the same gender and age are inserted.

```
(deftemplate person  (slot gender)  
                     (slot age (type INTEGER))   
                     (slot name))
```

**Edit**

Q1 from comment: A template (as the name implies) is just a "blueprint" for facts, and you can assert as many as you like.

Q2 from comment: If you add a rule like the following it'll print all Person facts at the end of the show. Note the low salience - if you omit it, the printout happens as soon as the fact is asserted.

```
(defrule print-all-persons
  (declare (salience -1000))
  (person (name ?name)(gender ?gender)(age ?age))
=>
  (printout t ?name " is a " ?age "-year old "
              (if (eq ?gender f) then "fe" else "") "male" crlf)
)
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. And, I have given the exact same (deftemplate) as you advised. Do I have to add multiple templates like that? But for the code that I have, it tells "when/after who a person can go.". And it stops when I choose 'n' for the final question. But I am not able to figure out, how to display all the person's age, gender, name that I have entered in a list when I select 'n' for the final question(say suppose after giving 4 men & 4 women). Please advice. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. i will try that and see if that works. Thanks much again.

Comment: Hello laune, I have edited my question. For some reason that rule is not getting executed. Please advice on that rule. Will it be useful if i provide my complete code to see where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Check the the result of `(facts)` after `(run)`. Are there any `person`facts?